# Wake on LAN from shutdown

Tags: windows, bios, shutdown, wake-on-lan

I'm having problems enabling Wake on LAN from shutdown on Lenovo B50-50 and Lenovo V15 G2 ITL computers.

There is no BIOS option to enable WOL. In Windows, in network adapter properties I enabled WOL, but it only works from Sleep mode.

Is there any way to enable WOL from shutdown in these cases or does it mean there is no such functionality on these PCs?

Comment: AFAIK, if the BIOS/UEFI firmware doesn't support WoL, it's an OS-level implementation only _(I haven't experimented with WoL within Windows in years, but thinking outside the box, most PCs/laptops support PXE boot, so a convoluted workaround could be remote booting to PXE if the Lenovo accepts that, then remotely rebooting the PC from the PXE image, as Windows supports remotely deploying Windows to a PC with no OS installed via PXE)_